# Nested Data structure

Tags: python, flask

I have the flask code below to query from sqlite.

```
@app.route('/recipe_pretty') 
@flask_login.login_required
def recipe_pretty():
    from functions.sqlquery import sql_query
    results2 = sql_query('''  SELECT  
                             REPLACE(R.Amount, '.0', '')  ||' ' || U.Name || "-" || I.Name || " (" || IT.Name ||")"  as AmountPretty,  R.SectionName  FROM Recipe as R
                            INNER JOIN Units as U on U.Id = R.UnitId
                            INNER JOIN Ingredient as I on I.Id = R.IngredientId
                            INNER JOIN IngredientType as IT on IT.Id = I.IngredientTypeId
                            INNER JOIN RecipeHeader as RH on RH.Id = R.RecipeId
                            ORDER BY R.SectionName''')
    
    

    
    return render_template('recipe_present.html', results2=results2)
```

This returns a list of SQlite rows.   The Sql_query function is list below this returns sqlite3.Rows into a List.  See the conn.row_factory.

```
DB  = env.str("DB_NAME")
# Create a database
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB, check_same_thread=False)

conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

# Make a convenience function for running SQL queries
def sql_query(query):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows
```

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oW2z.png)

I'm trying to loop through this in the following way to get the SectionName as sub header with the AmountPretty repeating under each SectionName.

```
  <ul>
                {% for section in results2 %}
                <li>
                <h2>{{section.SectionName}}</h2>
                <ul>
                    {% for ing in section %}
                    <li>{{ing.AmountPretty}}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

This isn't working.  I just get the list of SectionNames with no AmountPretty.  Do I need to split this single table into a nested list using the 2 columns for this to work?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please update the post with the object returned by your `sql_query` function instead of an image of a table

Answer (score 0):

I had to restructure the sql data with

```
lists = {}

for k, g in groupby(results2, key=lambda t: t['SectionName']):
   lists[k] = list(g)
```

That allowed me to access with this in my template :

```
  {% for list, items in lists.items() %}
              <div class="card text-sm" style="width: 18rem; margin-bottom: 50px;">
                  <div class="card-header">
                      <h3>{{ list }}</h3>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                      {% for item in items %}
                          <li class="list-group-item">
                            {{ item['AmountPretty'] }}
                          </li>
                      {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```